# Parametrized ansible task include - 'paramater is undefined'

Tags: ansible

I have problem using parametrized ansible include.

I have created following file, named *tasks/haproxy.xml*

```
 - name: "change node state to {{state}} in haproxy"
    tags:
    - "haproxy-{{state}}"
    become: yes
    become_user: root
    haproxy:
      state: "{{ state }}"
      wait: yes
      host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      backend: app
      socket: /var/container_data/haproxy/run/haproxy.sock
    delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{ groups.haproxy }}"
```

I am including this file in my playbook.yml, passing value of state parameter

```
  - include: tasks/haproxy.yml state=enabled
```

I am getting following error

```
TASK [include] *****************************************************************
included: /home/bb/tasks/haproxy.yml for 172.16.224.68, 172.16.224.69
ERROR! 'state' is undefined
```

state is my parameter, passed when doing include (as described in http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#task-include-files-and-encouraging-reuse)
Whats wrong?

I am using Ansible  2.0.2.0.

edit:
using alternative syntax for passing paramteres

```
 - include: tasks/haproxy.yml
    vars:
     state: enabled
```

gives exactly same error message.

Comment: Do you get the same result with the alternative (`vars`) syntax as described in the linked doc?

Comment: vars syntax gives same error message.

Comment: What about quoting, "enabled" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by removing single leading space (!!) when using alternative syntax (`vars`).

So correct parametrized include is

```
 - include: tasks/haproxy.yml
   vars:
    state: enabled
```

`vars` keyword must be at the same level as `include` keyword.
Otherwise it does not work, with message `ERROR! 'state' is undefined`.

Shortened syntax (`- include: tasks/haproxy.yml state=enabled`) still does not work.

Comment: I was attempting to do a "playbook include" not a "task include" and it appears that that doesn't support the passing of variables?